# Texture not rotating with the object

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I have a very simple object and a texture drown to it (using shader). Everything works great, except when rotating the object, the texture is not rotating along it, but appears to stay in the 2D space, creating the 'mask' effect below:

[Texture not rotating along the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRywd.png)

When I use a regular material and attach texture to it, all works fine, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong at the vertex shader.

I load the model the following way:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "models/cube.json", addModelToScene );

var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/woods.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 1.0, 1.0 );

uniforms = 
    {
        time: 
        { 
            type: "f", 
            value: 1.0 
        },
        texture1: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/woods.jpg" ) }

    };

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) {
      var material       = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
      var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial
      (
          {
              vertexShader:   $('#vertexshader').text(),
              fragmentShader: $('#fragmentshader').text(),
              uniforms:       uniforms
          }
      );

     model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );
     model.scale.set( 2.5, 2.5, 2.5 );
     scene.add( model );
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;

#ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
#endif

uniform float time;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;

#ifdef GL_ES
  precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform float time;

void main()
{
    vec2  u_resolution  = vec2( 1700, 1000 );
    vec2  uv            = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    gl_FragColor        = texture2D( texture1, uv );
}
```

And finally I rotate the object the following way:

```
model.rotation.z += 0.00013;
model.rotation.z += 0.004;
```

Why is the texture not one with the object, but instead stays in static position? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you should use `vUv` varying to address the texture, not `gl_FragCoord.xy`:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
```

`gl_FragColor.xy` is just pixel's (or, to be more accurate, fragment's) coordinates on a screen (i.e., window coordinates). They don't depend on rotation (or any transformations for that matter) of your object (or the object itself). They only depend upon where the pixel currently being shaded lies on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! when I did as you suggested, the object gets colored in a single color (the color that the first pixel of the texture is?). If I change textures I see it changing color, but not actually drawing the texture, just the same color. Any hints on what's going on?

Comment: Yes, the object probably lacks proper UV mapping. How do you obtain the model you're using? Maybe you need to check export UV option. Also, you maybe able to compute `uv` from vertex position, i.e. something like `vUv = (position.xy - minXY) / (maxXY - minXY), where `minXY` and `maxXY` are "bounds" of your model.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now! I was missing the UV mapping, I had a wrong assumption that it will just render the texture on the object anyway, just messed up.